# Add a member for certain template parameters of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, template-specialization

Consider a template class:

```
template <class First, class Second, class Third, class Fourth>
class MyClass;
```

What is the right way to add a member function for certain sets of template parameters?

For example, how to add a member `f()`, when `Second` is a `std::string()` ?

Here is the method I've found and I traditionally use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

template <class Container>
struct Array
{
    Container data;
    template <class... Dummy, 
              class = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Dummy) == 0>::type,
              class = typename std::enable_if<
                               std::tuple_size<
                               typename std::conditional<sizeof...(Dummy), 
                                                         Container, 
                                                         Container
                                                         >::type
                               >::value == 1
                               >::type
              >
    inline typename Container::value_type& value(Dummy...)
    {return data[0];}
};


int main()
{
    Array<std::array<double, 0>> array0; // Does not have the value() member
    Array<std::array<double, 1>> array1; // Have the value() member
    Array<std::array<double, 2>> array2; // Does not have the value() member
    Array<std::array<double, 3>> array3; // Does not have the value() member
}
```

It works well, but it's more a metaprogramming trick than a clean/standard way to do it.

Comment: If only you had C++1y listed as an option, then this is [easy](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3929.pdf).  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get the purpose of `Dummy` in your declaration. It can be done with two defaulted template parameters that are not used at all in function parameter list:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <class First> // arguments ommited for brevity
struct MyClass {
    template<
        typename U = First,
        typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<U, std::string>::value >::type
    >
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int> c1;
    MyClass<std::string> c2;
    // this is an error
    // c1.f();
    c2.f();    // this works
}
```

[**Live example.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bffb7cba93420665)

Note that it's possible to cheat: `c1.f<std::string>();` will still work.

Comment: The purpose of the dummy parameter was approximately the same as your U, but avoid cheating.

Comment: @Vincent I tip my hat to you,  sir :)

Answer (score 4):

You may use inheritance and specialization.
Something like:

```
template <typename T> struct Helper2 {};

template <> struct Helper2<std::string>
{
    void f() {};
};

template <class First, class Second, class Third, class Fourth>
struct MyClass : public Helper2<Second>
{
    // Normal code.
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<std::string, int, std::string, std::string> c1;
    MyClass<int, std::string, int, int> c2;
    //c1.f();     // this is an error
    c2.f();    // this works
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 but if you want to generalize this to multiple base classes, it can be convenient (especially on platforms that don't always use EBO for multiple inheritance) to use `class Helper<T, B>: B {};` and use base-class chaining. E.g. `MyClass: Helper1<Bla, Helper2<Meh>> {};` which will guarantee single inheritance. Boost.Operators uses this approach e.g.

Answer (score 1):

In C++1y concepts TS we have `requires` clauses that may let you do this easily.  See http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3929.pdf -- I may be wrong, however.

Outside of C++1y, your technique makes your program ill-formed with no diagnosis required, as all function `template`s **must** have at least one valid specialization.  As it happens, this is a very rarely enforced requirement, because solving for "there are no valid specializations" in the general case involves solving the halting problem.  Despite this, it is the programmers responsibility to ensure that all `template` functions have at least one valid set of `template` arguments.

The way I have found that is strictly legal for a zero-argument function in C++11 is to use CRTP based class specialization that eliminates the method in a specialization of the CRTP base.

Another way is to create a private, inaccessible type, and make that the only way to create a legal specialization in the case where you want to disable it.  Then privately inside the class you can cheat, but outside you cannot cheat.